# jQuery: Hide parent if child contains text number range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

I use a current jQuery selector to apply css to any elements containing certain keywords on **YouTube** as listed below:

```
$( '.feed-item-container:contains("Blah Blah") ') .css( {"display":"none"} );
```

My question is, how can it be changed so instead of using keyword detection, it can instead use a **number detection range** for each youtube feed on the subscriptions page(signed in)? If the element used to display the view count in the specific element "**.feed-item-container**", then how can that element(".feed-item-container") that displays each video/feed to apply css to hide it, but detect a number range for an element in it for "**.yt-lockup-meta-info**" containing **0 to 300** views?

To be clear, I do not need it to detect keywords and view count, only **removing the parent element** (by class selector) **if the child element** (by class selector) contains **1-300** views; already have jQuery to hide by keyword.

---

The closest I have gotten but incorrect:

```
$( ".feed-item-container:has(.yt-lockup-meta-info > :last-child)" ).slice(1, 300).css( "display", "none" );
```

I just realized moments later of why it wasn't working; thus realizing **.slice**, only selects elements and not number ranges such as **1-300**.

I understand this may or may not be a complicated problem, but my knowledge of jquery does not go down this path of understanding. Any help is much appreciated, but if solvable it would be very appreciated. This may help: http://jsfiddle.net/fVtaF/7/ + http://jsfiddle.net/eWweU/4/ (doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ads4p/), as a concept, would be helpful.

Using the JS `$('#containme').text().indexOf( i ) > -1`you can assign a variable to the .indexOf, and loop through a series of variables to see if there is a matching number in your element.

Lots of "overhead". I'm sure there are more elegant ways.

Comment: I have updated and tried to make it work as best as I could but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're asking, but if I understand you correctly maybe this fiddle will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/eWweU/3/

It uses jQuery to test every child of the `feed-item-container` class to see if it has a number from 0-300. If it does, it will hide that `feed-item-container` container.

Good luck.

Comment: if it doesn't select **.yt-lockup-meta-info > :last-child** as the child and only scan for 1-300 views, then any content even the dicription of the video for the parent element **.feed-item-container** will be hidden. It has to detect the number range in the specific element then hide the parent. This is an update to your jsfiddle of what I am trying to do (doesn't work) http://jsfiddle.net/eWweU/4/

Comment: yes, but the youtube feeds can show up to at least 15+ feeds (**.feed-item-container**) not to mention as you scroll and load more it can load dozens of feeds. It's also not seeming to work for an unknown reason. It is not hiding even one feed.

Comment: I use Jscript Tricks chrome extension, the rest of my code works, so I know it's not the extension being faulty. I appreciate all your help just to make that clear.